# First neo4j query taking more than expected time

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have an API in Django and its structure is something like -

```
FetchData():
  run cypher query1
  run cypher query2
  run cypher query3
  return
```

When I run these queries in neo4j query window each take around 100ms. But when I call this API, query1 takes **1s** and other 2 take expected **100ms** to execute. This pattern is repeated every time I call the API.

Can anyone explain what should be done here to run the first query in expected time.

Answer (score 1):

Neo4j tries to cache the graph in RAM. Upon first invocations caches are not warmed up yet, so it takes longer to do the IO operations. Subsequent invocations don't hit IO and read directly from RAM.

Comment: This caching is done every time I make API call? From what I read in other places on internet it does caching for the first few queries after the connection to the database is established.

Comment: The cache in on the server side. Every query you do first looks in the cache if the nodes/rels/properties you're asking for are already in the cache. Otherwise they get loaded from disk. If you need full speed from the first query, use or write a Neo4j extension that warms up caches upon startup.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds weird. The cache should only need to be warmed if the server or db is shut down, not after each of your API calls. Are you using paramterized queries? The only thing I can think of is maybe each set of queries is different causing them to have to be re-parsed and re-planned.